# Build Binary Tree from Preorder Traversal: Stack Overflow Error

Tags: java, recursion, tree, huffman-code, preorder

I have a tree where the leaves are marked with L and the non-leaf nodes are marked with I. I am given the preorder traversal of the tree. An example is IIILLILILLIIILLLIILILLL. I have to build the huffman tree for this included string. I originally pass in a new Root(), 0, and my treeString for my arguments. TreeString would be the string with the I's and L's pasted above. For some reason my code causes a StackOverflow exception to be thrown.  My code is as follows for the makeTree method:

```
public static void makeTree (BinaryNodeInterface<Character> root, int start, String treeString)
{
    if (treeString.charAt(start)=='L'){

        root.setLeftChild(null);
        root.setRightChild(null);
        return;
    }
    BinaryNodeInterface<Character> leftSide = new BinaryNode<Character>();
    root.setLeftChild(leftSide);
    makeTree(root.getLeftChild(), start++, treeString);
    BinaryNodeInterface<Character> rightSide = new BinaryNode<Character>();
    root.setRightChild(rightSide);
    makeTree(root.getRightChild(), start++, treeString);
}
```

I have no idea what is causing the stackoverflow exception to be thrown. I would think that my base case at the beginning would return and handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the problem:

```
makeTree(root.getLeftChild(), start++, treeString);
```

I'm not sure what your approach is, but it looks like if you see an `I`, your plan is to go to the left node, and start examining the string starting at the next character.

The reason for the infinite recursion is that `start++` is a post-increment operator, which means that it gives you the current value of `start` and then increments it.  Thus, each time `makeTree` calls itself, it calls itself with the same version of `start`, and thus looks at the same `I` in the input string.

**However, changing it to `++start` will not make things work.**  (It might avoid the stack overflow, but it won't work right.)  The reason is that when you call `makeTree`, you want to give it the starting location of the string where you want the recursive call to start looking--but you also want the recursive call to tell it how much of the string it consumed.  That is necessary because, after `makeTree` calls itself recursively on `getLeftChild`, you will call it again on `getRightChild`, and you need to call it with the correct starting point.

Note that each recursive invocation has its own copy of `start`.  Thus, when `makeTree` calls itself, and the second `makeTree` increments `start`, this has no effect on the `start` that the first `makeTree` sees.

You'll somehow need each recursive `makeTree` to tell its caller how much of the string it consumed.  Probably, the simplest way to do this is to change the return type to `int`; you can decide whether you want the function result to be the number of characters consumed, or the index where it stopped scanning, or something similar.  Then, after calling `makeTree` recursively, use the function result to adjust the `start` parameter.  Make sure `makeTree` returns the correct result, both in the leaf and the non-leaf cases.  Be careful to avoid off-by-one errors.

Comment: Had to totally re-do my tree but it ended up working. Thanks you. I didn't remember the differences between post and pre-increment operators

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a tree just from preOrder list.
Atleast you need inorder traversal as well OR if is full tree then you can also use posrorder.